# DB design confusion

Tags: sql

Below are the current DB table design

```
user table has user details
role table has role details (ex: admin, manager, supervisor)
permission table has permission details (ex: sales_order, purchase_order)
access table has 3 rows - read, update, write
role association table has role_id, per_id, access_id
role child association has user_id, role_id
```

currently the access is based on role level….

how to design the DB to make it more granular…

Now wants to change the design to access specific level instead of role level.

ex:

```
admin -> manager -> sales_order -> read 
admin -> manager -> purchase_order -> read and write.
```

please suggest how to design the tables so that we can achieve the expecation.

Thanks,

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What "more granular" means in your case?

Comment: lower level. instead of role specific now planning to go with access speicific...role would be a higher level